# Objective C - Is it possible to obtain the name or pointer to the object calling a method?

Tags: objective-c, logging

I have set up an Objective C logging class, however I would like to know the object that sent the message to the log class.

All of the logging examples seem to wrap the objective C classes around C macros, which entails that the logging will be in C function syntax; I would like to stick with an Objective C syntax.

Can anyone assist in how to retrieve the source of a message?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding where a method was called from.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614208/finding-where-a-method-was-called-from)

Answer (score 0):

Nope;  can't be done.  At least, not consistently and, even then, not without a massive performance hit.

This seems to be coming up often lately.

[Finding where a method was called from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614208/finding-where-a-method-was-called-from)

Comment: Thanks - no idea how I missed that when searching earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I usually pass information from the caller to `NSLog` by:

```
 NSLog(@"%@::%@", [[self class] description], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

Not sure whether it is what you want though.